# how to take result of aggregation/JSON to update a collection document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am making a polling website. Currently I have two collections Polls and Votes. I am using the aggregation pipeline to get the number of votes for each movie. I am having difficulty wrapping my head around updating the poll based on the vote collection. This is the vote Schema:

```
poll: objectId
votedMovies: Array
   0: Object
      id: ObjectId
      title: string
```

This is my poll Schema:

```
_id: ObjectID
pollType: String
totalVotes: Number
movies: Array
   0: Object
      id: ObjectID
      title: String
      votes: Number
```

So far I have an aggregation pipeline that does the following:

```
let voteCollection = await db.collection('votes').aggregate([

    {
        $match: {poll: id}
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$votedMovies"
    },
    {
        $group: {_id: "$votedMovies.id", totalVotes: {$sum: 1}}
    }
   ]).toArray()
```

That spits out something like this:

```
[{"_id":10674,"totalVotes":2},
{"_id":99861,"totalVotes":1},
{"_id":299534,"totalVotes":4},
{"_id":637157,"totalVotes":3},
{"_id":24428,"totalVotes":5}]
```

How do I update the poll document so that it has the current number of votes? Am I on the right track with the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: You need to update each `poll` with the returned `totalVotes` value, correct?

Comment: yes. I need to update votes for the matching id movie in the poll. @Ipizzinidev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to update each movie votes with:

```
for (const vote of voteCollection) {
  await db.collection('polls').updateOne(
    {
      _id: id, // pool id
      'movies._id': vote._id,
    },
    {
      'movies.$.votes': vote.totalVotes,
    }
  );
}
```